# компиляция python в exe

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]здраствуйте,решил скомпилировать код python в exe , в итог , во вре[image: введите сюда описание изображения]мя компиляции установились не все модули , а именно не отсановился модуль pyttsx3

Comment: буду безумнно благодарен , если поможете

Comment: Оформите вопрос в соответствии с правилами. Замените картинки текстом